# I need a reliable StopWatch in Swift 3

Tags: swift, timer

I need a reliable StopWatch in Swift 3. I came up with this based on another example found on SO ...

```
import Foundation

class StopWatch {
    public private(set) var seconds:Double = 0
    public var milliseconds: Double { return seconds * 1000 }     
    private weak var timer:Timer?
    private var startTime:Double = 0
    public private(set) var started = false       
    public func start() {
        if started { return }
        started = true
        startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true) {
            timer in
            if !self.started { return }
            self.seconds = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - self.startTime
            print("Seconds: \(self.seconds)")
        }
        print("Started")
    }

    public func stop() {
        if !started { return }
        timer?.invalidate()
        started = false
        print("Stopped")
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work reliably. Fetching seconds are often staying at 0 or in other cases when accessing seconds they don't start from 0. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Could you paste how did you use it?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a threading issue. If UI is involved you have to make sure that the UI related code runs on the main thread.

The variable `started` is redundant. Checking the timer for `nil` does the same.

This code adds a `DispatchQueue.main` block. Put your code to update the UI into this block

```
class StopWatch {
    public private(set) var seconds:Double = 0
    public var milliseconds: Double { return seconds * 1000 }
    private weak var timer : Timer?
    private var startTime : Double = 0
    private var timerIsRunning : Bool { return timer != nil }

    public func start() {
        if timerIsRunning { return }
        startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.seconds = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - self.startTime
            print("Seconds: \(self.seconds)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // do something on the main thread
            }
        }
        print("Started")
    }

    public func stop() {
        if !timerIsRunning { return }
        timer!.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        print("Stopped")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My time measuring isn't related to any UI stuff though. I'm wondering about the `withTimeInterval` param however. I suppose this is milliseconds. The API doc is rather unclear about it.

Comment: If you need a more accurate timer use `DispatchTimer`